# Centrar texto boton Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

**Buenas, quisiera saber como centrar un texto en un `botón` en `AndroidStudio`. Este es mi código:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/negro"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearGrabarIcono"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="¡Atención!"
                android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearGrabarIcono">
            <TextView
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:text="Elija una opción."
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:textColor="@color/rojo"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/escribir"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/grabar"
                android:textColor="@color/rojo"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Intento usando esta línea:

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Pero, se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Por default viene centrado con su margenes. El error debe ser que el button de escribir es mas grande que el de grabar para ver las caracteristicas de las vistas tienes el LayoutInspector. Lo abres en view -> tools windows -> layoutInspector

Comment: nos puedes compartir el código completo de tu layout?

Comment: listo, lo he añadido @Coeus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Primero debes de revisar tu codigo para no generar ID's innecesarios en el sistema por ejemplo:

[image: captura de error]

En el linearLayout encerrado utilizas el atributo  `android:layout_below="@+id/linearGrabarIcono"` el cual es innecesario dentro de un linearLayout y si no utilizas el layout con ID `linearGrabarIcono` puedes eliminarlo.

2. El tamaño del texto se mide en `sp` y no en `dp`

[image: captura error]

3. Evita tamaños definidos explícitamente ejemplo: `width="400dp"` ya que en un dispositivo con menos `dp` no se vera gran parte de su contenido, trata utilizar `match_parent` o `wrap_content`.
4. Utilizas muchos layouts simplemente para dar un margen a los `textView` que tienes dentro, esto generara una carga adicional en el dispositivo.

Te recomiendo le des una vista a la documentacion [aqui](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout)

Ahora si, después de revisar todo el layout y con respecto a tu pregunta lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/escribir"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="escribir"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/grabar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="grabar"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Este es el layout que contiene los botones de acción, modifique lo siguiente:

1. Cada boton tenia un margen superior de 15dp, se lo coloque al padre y asi evitar repetir codigo.
2. Para que cada boton tome la mitad del dialog se define en el layout padre `android:weightSum="2"` y en cada widget `android:layout_weight="1"`, con esto divide el padre en 2 y cada boton ocupara 1.
3. Hay muchos colores ya integrados que puedes utilizar y evitar crearlos o repetirlos en el archivo color, puedes acceder a ellos con `@android:color/EL_COLOR_QUE_NECESITES`.
4. No me acuerdo que mas cambios le hice, en fin, te comparto el layout completo

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="¡Atención!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Elija una opción."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/escribir"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="escribir"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/grabar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="grabar"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Al parecer tratas de hacer un `alertDialog` personalizado. Te recomiendo leer esta documentacion para que todo quede mas guapo y ahorres mucho trabajo.

- Documentacion oficial de android [aqui](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs)
- Material design [aqui](https://material.io/develop/android/components/dialogs)

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha servido tu explicación